# Omnetpp-5.6.1 WIndows installation issues

Tags: omnet++

OMNeT++-5.6.1 Windows installation issue.
 Qtenv is not getting configured.
 The other issue is it is not being able to recognize the %HOME% path.
 Can anybody help?

Issue 1: 
cat: /c/Users/Abhirup: No such file or directory
cat: "Roy/Desktop/MoSim'20/Omnet++/omnetpp-5.6.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.1//Vers                                                                                                                                  ion": No such file or directory
Welcome to !

Issue 2: checking for Qt5 with CFLAGS=" -std=c++11   -isystem C:/Users/Abhirup Roy/Desktop/MoSim'20/Omnet++/omnetpp-5.6.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/include -isystem C:/Users/Abhirup Roy/Desktop/MoSim'20/Omnet++/omnetpp-5.6.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/include/QtCore -isystem C:/Users/Abhirup Roy/Desktop/MoSim'20/Omnet++/omnetpp-5.6.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/include/QtGui -isystem C:/Users/Abhirup Roy/Desktop/MoSim'20/Omnet++/omnetpp-5.6.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/include/QtWidgets -isystem C:/Users/Abhirup Roy/Desktop/MoSim'20/Omnet++/omnetpp-5.6.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/include/QtOpenGL -isystem C:/Users/Abhirup Roy/Desktop/MoSim'20/Omnet++/omnetpp-5.6.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/include/QtPrintSupport   -isystem C:/Users/Abhirup Roy/Desktop/MoSim'20/Omnet++/omnetpp-5.6.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/include -isystem C:/Users/Abhirup Roy/Desktop/MoSim'20/Omnet++/omnetpp-5.6.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/include/QtCore -isystem C:/Users/Abhirup Roy/Desktop/MoSim'20/Omnet++/omnetpp-5.6.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/include/QtGui -isystem C:/Users/Abhirup Roy/Desktop/MoSim'20/Omnet++/omnetpp-5.6.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/include/QtWidgets -isystem C:/Users/Abhirup Roy/Desktop/MoSim'20/Omnet++/omnetpp-5.6.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/include/QtOpenGL -isystem C:/Users/Abhirup Roy/Desktop/MoSim'20/Omnet++/omnetpp-5.6.1-src-windows/omnetpp-5.6.1/tools/win64/mingw64/include/QtPrintSupport" LIBS=" -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework QtWidgets -framework QtPrintSupport -framework QtOpenGL"... no
configure: error: Cannot build Qt apps, probably due to missing or too old Qt packages. Make sure Qt development packages are installed and newer than Qt 5.4. You can disable Qtenv by setting the WITH_QTENV variable to "no" in configure.user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to unpack and compile OMNeT++ in the directory, whose path does not contain a space.