# Occurs some problem during "./configure" command execute in OMNeT++

Tags: qt, omnet++

I tried to install OMNeT++ 5.6.2 on my laptop, but I'm getting the some errors.

First, my laptop detail specify is below:

- OS version: macOS (Catalina 10.15.5)

And I did install dependency software like a "gdb", "JRE", "JDK". So I tried command execute "./configure" in "omnetpp-5.6.2" folder after create certificate for "gdb".

But I met some error like below:

```
checking for Qt5 with CFLAGS=" -std=c++11   -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtGui -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtOpenGL -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtPrintSupport   -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtGui -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtOpenGL -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtPrintSupport" LIBS="-lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lQt5Widgets -lQt5PrintSupport -lQt5OpenGL -L/Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/lib -Wl,-rpath=/Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/lib"... no
checking for Qt5 with CFLAGS=" -std=c++11   -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtGui -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtOpenGL -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtPrintSupport   -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtGui -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtOpenGL -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtPrintSupport" LIBS="-lQtGui5 -lQtCore5 -lQtWidgets5 -lQtPrintSupport5 -lQtOpenGL5"... no
checking for Qt5 with CFLAGS=" -std=c++11   -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtGui -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtOpenGL -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtPrintSupport   -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtGui -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtOpenGL -isystem /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtPrintSupport" LIBS="-L/Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/lib -F/Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/lib -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework QtWidgets -framework QtPrintSupport -framework QtOpenGL"... no
configure: error: Cannot build Qt apps, probably due to missing or too old Qt packages. Make sure Qt development packages are installed and newer than Qt 5.4. You can disable Qtenv by setting the WITH_QTENV variable to "no" in configure.user.
```

Why am I getting the above error?

Strangely, running the "qmake -v" command in the "omnetpp-5.6.2" folder outputs the following:

```
kimminwoo@Macbook-Pro-2020-13-inch-for-Minwoo omnetpp-5.6.2 % qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.6.1 in /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/lib
```

I think it is higher than the version mentioned in the above error. But I don't know why it didn't finish normally.

Thank you for read :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61407631/omnetpp-5-6-1-windows-installation-issues "Unpack in path having no space and compile"

Comment: @Sawa i Thanks your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution this problem.

I did download "omnetpp-5.6.2-src-macosx.tgz" from OMNeT++ official site. And this file decompressed that moved to Desktop folder.

I tried to decompress using macOS default archive utility tool. But it's wrong way. We must use "tar" command in terminal. If you used to "tar" command in "omnetpp-5.6.2-src-macosx.tgz", you are not meet above problem.